# $.png instead of status.php?channel=$

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've got a problem with my .htaccess.

I have a script called status.php which shows information about the user depending on the name used, like status.php?channel=Kazuto. This script shows the information as a png image.

This is not the best solution for boards or forums which only allow images via BBCode as their signatures, so I want to trick it and rewrite so that it can also be accessed via Kazuto.png

But for some reason it does not work properly.

`hitbox.kazuto.de/status.php?channel=Kazuto` > `hitbox.kazuto.de/Kazuto.png`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+status\.php\?channel=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.png? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)\.png$ status.php?channel=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Would anyone mind helping me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RewriteRule` you have a preceeding `/`, which should not be there.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+status\.php\?channel=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.png? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.png$ status.php?channel=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also, no need to escape the `.` inside character class of patterns.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never have noticed that.